# Why getTimezoneOffset value depends on date?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Why `getTimezoneOffset()` returns different timezone offset values based on provided date? I expect the results to be the same as i'm not changing my local timezone between each call.

```
new Date('2016-05-01T03:24:00Z').getTimezoneOffset()
> -120
new Date('1950-05-01T03:24:00Z').getTimezoneOffset();
> -60
new Date('1900-05-01T03:24:00Z').getTimezoneOffset();
> -84
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset#gettimezoneoffset_and_historical_data

Comment: _"as i'm not changing my local timezone between each call."_ - what does that have to do with anything? Even if you live in one of those places where you have to adjust your _clock_ by an hour twice a year, that doesn't mean that you are actually changing your _time zone_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) points a few times for your question.

On "[Varied results in Daylight Saving Time (DST) regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset#varied_results_in_daylight_saving_time_dst_regions)" section;

> In a region that annually shifts in and out of Daylight Saving Time
> (DST), as date varies, the number of minutes returned by calling
> `getTimezoneOffset()` **can be non-uniform**.
>
> Note: `getTimezoneOffset()`'s behavior will never differ based on the
> time when the code is run — its behavior is always consistent when
> running in the same region. **Only the value of date affects the result**.

On "[getTimezoneOffset() and DST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset#gettimezoneoffset_and_dst)" secion;

> In regions that use DST, **the return value may change based** on the time
> of the year date is in.

On "[getTimezoneOffset() and historical data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset#gettimezoneoffset_and_historical_data)" section;

> Due to historical reasons, the timezone a region is in can be
> constantly changing, even disregarding DST. For example, below is the
> output in a runtime in Shanghai, where the timezone is UTC+08:00.

```
const shModernOffset = new Date('2022-01-27').getTimezoneOffset(); // -480
const shHistoricalOffset = new Date('1943-01-27').getTimezoneOffset(); // -540
```

So, getting different results seems normal to me.

Comment: akbank yine gümlemiş Mr.Gönül, sizi oraya sevk etmeliler, çok maytap geçilmeye başlandı artık. https://www.donanimhaber.com/akbank-coktu-mu-akbank-kredi-karti-ekstreleri-ikiye-katlandi--154480